# How to combine coordinates into one svg element in D3?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, d3.js

I'm working on a visualization with pixel data and I have been able to successfully load data onto the canvas. Data is about the type of clouds on the globe. There are about 12 types. Every type has a color on the map. Right now I'm basically plotting every coordinate of the pixel where the color is of a specific cloud and then creating svg for it and loading it too the canvas. But when I plot the pixel data, it creates too many svg's.

However, some of the pixels are like next to each other and I was thinking that is there any way I can join those two pixels that are next to each other. I have a list of coordinates:

```
Cloud1 = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), .... ]
```

In this case I would combine the four coordinates into one svg, since they are next to each other.

Also, one more thing, How many svg's can you load into a browser(max) at once without any lag?

Image URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/beB8f.png

Comment: Why not have one SVG for everything and create one `rect` element for each pixel?

Comment: That is what I did. I have a svg of a map, and then I create rect for each pixel. I will link an image. see updated question.

Comment: Without testing your specific example, if you have more than a few hundred points to plot, SVG is probably going to be too slow for you, and you should probably consider Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the specific question of joining pixels that are adjacent to each other, use a bin method to accumulate touching/adjacent pixels.

Sort all the cloud's pixels by their pixel position (x,y). Iterate through each pixels, check against all existing bins(arrays of pixels), and if none are touching any points in any of the bins, create a new bin with that pixel as the first item. If the current pixel touches an item in the first bin found, add that pixel to that bin and go to the next pixel in the cloud.

After all the pixels in cloud have been divided into separate bins, get the outer x,y values of each bin to draw a polyline representing the subcloud. So essentially you have 1 svg representing each bin.

This should reduce your number of svg elements greatly and you have the added bonus of colouring the area of the polyline cloud with an opaque color which may overlay other cloud type very nicely.